# How to order by children key value using Firebase?

Tags: typescript, sorting, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to sort a list of status using Firebase, here is how the tree looks like :

[image]

What I tried :

```
   var statusList=[];
    firebase.database().ref(myref).once('value', function (snapStatus) {
      snapStatus.forEach(function (status) {
        statusList.push({
          'label':status.key,
          'date':status.val()
        });
        return false;
      });
   });
```

However, it is not sorting it correctly, is it possible to order by the most recent status (earlier timestamp) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `orderByValue`, which sorts the child nodes by their value.

So:

```
var statusList=[];
firebase.database().ref('status').orderByValue().once('value', function (snapStatus) {
  snapStatus.forEach(function (status) {
    ...
```